# Issue installing vim plugins

Tags: vim

So i'm rocking a VIM version 6.3.82 on rhel 4.9... which i'd imagine is the biggest culprit. (no chance of an upgrade any time soon)

I downloaded the latest Rails.vim and have installed this many times on my home machine.

I try the command :Rails! and i Get "e493: Not an editor command."

In my .vimrc i've added

```
set nocompatible
syntax on
filetype plugin indent on
```

Am i doomed with a dated vim to use most any plugins?  Am i missing something in my .vimrc to enable vim plugins?

Any direction is appreciated. :p-

TIA,
  Kirby

Comment: Try [pathogen](https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen) to manage your plugins. See [here](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/synchronizing-plugins-with-git-submodules-and-pathogen/) (or [here](http://tammersaleh.com/posts/the-modern-vim-config-with-pathogen)) for a guide.

Comment: Why don't you install the latest vim? I know RHEL is not up to date (even RHEL 6 does not have the latest), but there's nothing preventing you from installing the latest vim...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to use an old version of Rails.vim it looks like. The last version that worked with Vim 6 is version 2.1:

http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1567

You may be able to compile your own version of vim in your home directory if you want to use the latest Vim and Rails.vim.

Comment: i believe the answer is to install the latest vim.  thanks guys!